# Won't trigger authentication window in LinkedIn App on iPad

Tags: ios, ipad, linkedin-api

We have successfully integrated Linkedin iOS sdk in our app.It works perfectly on iPhone devices. But when i am trying it in iPad, it doesn't work. Problem is that, it won't authenticating in iPad. It just opens linkedin home page but doesn't redirecting to App. It remains stuck on linkedin home page. Even i also tried Linked ios sdk samples on iPad.

```
func application(application: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: AnyObject?) -> Bool {
    if LISDKCallbackHandler.shouldHandleUrl(url) {
        return LISDKCallbackHandler.application(application, openURL: url, sourceApplication: sourceApplication, annotation: annotation)
    }
    return true
}
```

Either the auth screen or the code above won't be triggered on iPad.

Comment: I have the same problem, on my iPhone it works great, authentication is called and LinkedIn app returns to my own application. On my iPad it stays stuck on LinkedIn homepage, nothing happening. I think it's a bug in de LinkedIn SDK/app.

Comment: Hello,  i am facing same problem with authentication using linked in app / browser ..  Not appearing  authentication window and retuning to app...using latest linkedIn sdk Thnx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not really an answer since SO wont let me comment yet. Confirming I'm seeing the same thing. FWIW, on the iPhone, the app did not present the auth screen when I was not already logged in to the LI app. When already logged into LI, the LI app presents the auth screen as expected. On iPad, the app does not present the auth screen under any circumstances. This behavior is exhibited in the LI SDK sample app. Hoping someone can answer this as the users of our app will likely be using an iPad rather than iPhone.

Comment: Yeah. LinkedIn engineers, you hear that? It is a really unacceptable flaw for a listed company!